# Sql server Fulltext index Rank features with Datetime

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm a fresh man in SQL Server Fulltext Index service.
Now I have a PostBody table with 3 columns

```
(PostID bigint, PostBody nvarchar（max）,CreatedDate datetime2(7)).
```

I'm using the Table varible function `ContainsTable` to get the top 100 ranked results. But I also need to add one more feature `CreatedDate` that will be make the results more reasonable. The latest and matched results should be shown.

```
select top 100 p.*,rp.Rank from PostBody p, ContainsTable(PostBody,Body,'mvc',100) as rp
where p.PostID=rp.Key
order by rp.Rank desc
```

But How will be CreatedDate take into consider?

I will be very appreciate for your help.
Regards,

David

Comment: `CreatedDate` is already in your results. You select `p.*` which means all columns from PostBody. Your result set will have columns: PostID, PostBody, CreatedDate, Rank

Comment: Thank you buddy. I do not only want to get the Post's CreatedDate. There are many recent posts ranked at a low level. So I want to make the recent posts rank higher.

Comment: SQL Server does not natively support weighing full text results by another column (CreatedDate in your case). You'll need to calculate your own weight and factor it into the Rank.